# REST - how to handle validating errors in single page application

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, validation, reactjs

When I submit the form via REST, and get validation errors, I want to preserve the fields that are valid and restore the existing values that failed validation, and show a message that those fields failed.

This is easy with server side rendering using the Spring MVC, but what is the best approach to do this on client side? I know I could return custom error object, and make a javascript function which will intercept it and set the fields accordingly.

But is there some library or pattern that reduces the boilerplate of feedback about validation errors on client side? I'm working on React and Spring.

**Edit**

By validation I don't mean only the correct datatype and length of the input fields, but some constraints depending of the internal state of the object and it's relations according to the business rules. Client should only validate the datatype, and server should perform business validation. And the question is, how to handle those validation failures in the server, such as described above.

Answer (score 0):

How about the JQuery Validation Plugin?
https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to adapt some sort of framework. My personal preference for form validation is AngularJs.

It comes out of the box with directives to check input required, and regex validation, min /max.. and a few other.

In collaboration with ngMessages directive it can be a smooth experience.

please check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms for more info..
cheers

to give you an example consider the elegance of the following code:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
    Enter your name:
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-minlength="5"
           ng-maxlength="20"
           required />
  </label>
  <pre>myForm.myName.$error = {{ myForm.myName.$error | json }}</pre>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm using React. The problem is, I would need to duplicate the validation logic both in the client and the server. It's not only about the correct datatype and length, but there are some constraints to the input, depending of the internal state of the object and it's relations according to the business rules. Best solution would be to perform the validation *only* on the server side, and only render the validation errors on the client.